# Get Element Type from SelectNodes result with HtmlAgility

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I'd like to find out what element type I got in my loop when using htmlagility 1.4

I got this simple table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h2>Title1</h2>
      <p>Text...</p>
      <h2>Title2</h2>
      <p>More Text...</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I load it with

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(tableString);
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table/tr/td/*");
foreach (var infoNode in node)
{
    // Print the actual element type
    Console.WriteLine(infoNode.InnerText.Trim());
}
```

I could of course analyze the infoNode.OuterHtml but that sucks a bit. And the infoNode.NodeType simply returns 'Element'

Anyone keen to help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the answer was to use the Name property

```
infoNode.Name
```